# Python. Import specific characters from a .txt file

Tags: python, variables, text, import, character

I have a .txt file which consist of;

```
A!
B@
C3
```

etc. I want to import each character as a different variable, such as the end result being that e.g.

```
line1_char1 = "A"
line1_char2 = "!"
line2_char1 = "B"
```

ect. Does anyone know how to code this properly in python?

I think I need to do something along the lines on;

```
ci = open("myfile.txt")
line1_char1 = ci.read(1,1)
line1_char2 = ci.read(1,2)
line2_char1 = ci.read(2,1)
ci.close
```

ect. Am I nearly correct on this and what do I need to do to get it working?

Comment: You may want to use arrays.

Comment: @devnull Unfortunately what i'm trying to do cannot use arrays, i need to have different variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my favorite way to read characters from a file is by using a list comprehension like so:

```
f=open(textfile, 'r')
while 1:
    line=f.readline().strip() #this gets rid of the newline character
    if line=='':# if there are no more lines, quit looping
        f.close()
        break
    characters=[line[i] for i in range(len(line))] this splits up every character of the line into its own item in a list.  NOTE THIS WILL INCLUDE SPACES AND PUNCTUATION
```

As for using those characters as variable names, I think you may want to try a dictionary.  for every character you read from the file, assign that value as a key in a dictionary like this

```
tempdict=dict()
f=open(textfile, 'r')
while 1:
    x=f.readline().strip()
    if x=='':
        f.close()
        break
    x=[x[i] for i in range(len(x))]
    for node in x:
        tempdict[node]=''
```

now you can call up each one of those characters by calling

```
tempdict[charactername]
```

and either assigning a value or retrieving a value.

---

UPDATE

```
characterslist=[]
f=open('putyourtextfilenamehere','r')
while 1:
    x=f.readline().strip()
    if x=='':
        f.close()
        break
    x=[x[i] for i in range(len(x))]
    for j in x:
        characterslist.append(j)
```

that should read each line and save the characters into a list called characterslist

Comment: Thank you so much it is almost working. I didn't really understand the dictionary however the list comprehension is almost working for me. It's just I have 6 characters in total to import and so far i can only import 2, the 'N' and '%' by doing characters[0] and characters[1]. How do I get all 6?

Comment: each pair of characters in the example you gave are on different lines.  Thats why i put the while 1: loop in there.  use the while 1: part and then read each line then add the characters in that list to another list and you'll get all of them.  I'll update my code for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now! :D. You can tell i'm new to coding.